# Using uniroot in R with integrate

Tags: r, integrate

Hello I would like some help on how to use some functions in R.
I have to find the value of a parameter that satisfies my equation. My equation is an integral. So I have to find  a way to combine those two functions. The value of a must be less than 5

```
INTEGRAND<- function(x,a){exp(-x*a)*(1-exp(-sqrt(a)) }
INTEGRAL <- function(a){(integrate(INTEGRAND,lower=0, upper=Inf))$value - 1}
root<- uniroot(INTEGRAL,interval=c(0.01,4.99))
```

But to calculate the integral we need a value for 'a' but the is is what I am searching for.

Comment: What's `t`? Some parameter?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `uniroot` it may make this more clear to you. They explicitly define their `a` and set it within `uniroot`. FYI there are other mistakes in your functions though.

Comment: @Lyngbakr Fixed it. I meant a not t